# Remove duplicate sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

I have a complex SQL query that can be simplified to the below:

```
Select ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD
From MyTable
Where (ColA In (Select ItemID From Items Where ItemName like '%xxx%') 
    or ColB In (Select ItemID From Items Where ItemName like '%xxx%'))
```

As you can see, the sub-query appears twice. Is the compiler intelligent enough to detect this and gets the result of the sub-query only once? Or does the sub-query run twice?

FYI, table Items has about 20,000 rows and MyTable has about 200,000 rows.

Is there another way to re-write this SQL statement so that the sub-query appears/runs only once?

Update: The Where clause in the main query is dynamic and added only when needed (i.e. only when a user searches for 'xxx'). Hence changes to the main select statement or re-structuring of the query are not possible.

Comment: Perhaps creating a (materialized) view is an option?

Comment: As you are given a `OR` statement, the first sub-query runs and only if ColA is not there the second query runs. Anyway compiler is not intelligent enof to identify the logic of subquery

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, in the original query, MyTable is actually a complex view. Making changes to that view is out of scope.

Comment: If you do not want / are not allowed to change the query structurally: What kind of help do you expect?

Comment: Is there a better way to write the where clause?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### UPDATE Your request not to change the query, just the `WHERE`

You can pack the CTE directly in the place where it is called (untested):

```
Select ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD
From MyTable
Where EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (Select i.ItemID 
                             From Items AS i 
                             Where iItemName like '%xxx%') AS itm 
              WHERE itm.ItemID=MyTable.ColA OR itm.ItemID=MyTable.ColB)
```

#### previous

I think this should be the same...

```
WITH MyCTE AS
(
    Select ItemID From Items Where ItemName like '%xxx%'
)
Select ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD
From MyTable
Where EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyCTE WHERE ItemID=ColA OR ItemID=ColB)
```

A substring `LIKE` search is - for sure - not performant.

If you can reduce your "Items" to just a few rows with your `LIKE` filter, you must test which is fastest.

Comment: Thanks! But the sub-query is part of dynamic SQL that is added only if required. The original query must stay intact. Only the part after the where clause can be changed.

Comment: @navigator, This is a piece of information you *really* should give in your question...

Comment: Looks very promising... Am checking the solution in the original query. Reverting soon...

Comment: FANTASTIC!!! The change reduced my query time from 45 seconds to 5 seconds. I wish I could give more points to this!!! Accepted Answer!

Comment: @navigator, I'm glad to help you, happy coding!

Comment: Wouldn't the sub query in the EXISTS part even be simpler like this: `... Where iItemName like '%xxx%' AND ( ItemID = MyTable.ColA OR ItemID=MyTable.ColB )` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also write the query like this:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD
FROM MyTable
WHERE EXISTS(
  (SELECT ItemID FROM Items WHERE ItemName LIKE '%xxx%') 
  INTERSECT
  SELECT t.v FROM (VALUES (ColA), (ColB)) AS t(v) )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that it will follow the actual execution order. It depends on how you write a query. Identical subqueries are normally only performed once.
There is a `WITH` clause in standard SQL.

```
WITH mySubQuery AS
(
  [the subquery code]
)

SELECT * FROM
    mySubQuery AS sq
WHERE xyz IN (mySubQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL programmers can use CTE (Common Table Expression) in such cases

You can define a CTE using the sub-query once and use it in the SQL statement by referencing more than once.

Please refer to [SQL CTE Common Table Expression tutorial](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) for samples
CTE's are very powerful tools for SQL developers especially when used as recursive-queries